# can't import google cloud message service on android studio os x

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm stuck in android studio; I'm iOS developer new to Android. I'm trying to do a simple webView app with push notifications.

As you can see in my mainActivity.java the import statement is in gray and the `checkPlayServices()` is in red. I've done all the steps in the [official tutorial] and I have installed everything you can install (35GB) from the SDK manager. I've also checked if the SDK directory were correct. Here are screenshots of the mainActivity, manifest file, build.grapple and activity_main.xml.

[1](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkPlayServices()` is in red because you dont have such a method. Include this method on your class:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

check [Android GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) for more information

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. The snippet is from: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-play, where you use GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable().

Comment: I have included the method in my mainActivity.java but now i have 
GooglePlayServicesUtil in red in the int declaration

Comment: For simplicity if you are using `Android Studio` go to `project structure->dependencies` and on the top right you have a green plus sign. Click on it and choose `Library Dependency`. There you will see google play dependency, import it. Also check imports if added

Comment: I've finally done it. It was the import sentence, I had to press alt+enter to "link" the import sentence with every "red word" in the text and then they become black, and now they don't cause errors when compile, but what the ... is this?? Isn't Android studio supposed to do this automatically? Why there is nothing of this in any tutorial??

Comment: and the "funny" thing is my import sentence is still in gray and it says it's unused. I really don't understand this ide

Comment: If you dont use anything from that import it will say so ofc, hence you better update your question with the new issue so we can see whats happening